# Google Maps Javascript API quota is set to 1

Tags: api, maps, limit, quota

I'm receiving this error when using Maps Javascript API

[Maps error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AKCo.png)

Apparently, it's because I have exceeded my quota limit; however Google states I have up to 100,000 requests per 24 hours ([Google Usage Limits](https://www.google.com.br/search?rlz=1C1CHBD_enBR771BR771&ei=6-RlW_eXI8mbwQT6sYKQDg&q=google%20maps%20api%20usage%20limits&oq=google%20maps%20javascript%20quota%20free&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0i71k1l8.0.0.0.3584.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.HLghW4YwGOk))

When I access Gmy API dashboard, it states my quota limit is one on "Map loads per day".

[Google quota limit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDbb8.png)

Appreciate your help, tnks

Comment: Because of your billing acount country is is blacklist. Some countries now are stopped for using Google map Javascript API. I have this problem too, then try to add new billing account with US region then the map back to work. (info: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-prohibited-territories/)

Answer (score 5):

I've been having this issue too - however Google documentation contradicts itself in places.

According to ["Detailed guide for users of the standard Google Maps JavaScript API"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) - Enable Billing (step 7) is ***optional.***

Yet clicking more info gives you **"You must enable billing on each of your projects"** - it's all a bit irritating as this causes confusion for clients (as well as devs!)

OpenStreetMaps is a nice alternative, bit harder to get up and running with and no nice scroll block by default. I'm currently switching to this while Google alienate their userbase

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need to have billing enabled on the account now, tried with 2 gsuites account, limit is 1 without billing account attached and unlimited with billing account attached.

Edit: see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing?hl=en_US

> Important: Enable Billing As of July 16, 2018, to continue to use the
>   Google Maps Platform APIs, you must enable billing on each of your
>   projects. If you choose not to add a billing account, your maps will
>   be degraded, or other Maps API requests will return an error.